# Opening an App inside Another App Using Deep Linking with Custom Url React native(Andorid)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

Am new to React-native. We are trying to implement a react-native App in which a button will be provided so that whenever a user clicks on the button he will be directed to play store if the app is not installed. If the App is already installed on the button click he should be able to open the app which is currently not happening.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
  </category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">
  </category>
    <data  android:scheme="whatsapp"></data>
 </intent-filter>
```

Above is the code which we modified with in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

> App.js
>   We have a method called **handle()** which will handle the events

```
 handle(){
 let appName = 'whatsapp';
 let url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp';
 Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => {
  if (err.code === 'EUNSPECIFIED') {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          Linking.openURL(
            url
          );
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Could not open ${appname}. ${err.toString()}`);
      }
    });}
```

The above code is working fine for opening an app in Playstore. But when the app is installed already in the device it on the button click it should directly open the App using Custom url.

When we are using **canOpenURL()** with Custom Url schema it does nothing. And when i use Custom Url schema with **openURL()** it is giving me a warning saying no action is provided or defined in the **android.intent.action.VIEW** but it is provided.

```
const url = 'whatsapp://';
   Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
      console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
 }else {
      return Linking.openURL(url);
}
 }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Please help us. Thanks in Advace!!

Comment: same url schema should be used in 2 different apps. It is will provide the intent chooser if it happens.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you be more specific with the answer you have provided with an example @AmrutBidri

Comment: @unknown could you please share the code if this was solved? I am stuck doing the same thing I can not find correct appName and url for the app I am working with. could you please tell me how to find it?

Comment: Hi @newdeveloper, if you want to know the app URL. Open your browser search for play store in that search for the app you are working with click on the app. In the address bar, you can see the Id and appName of that particular app.